# NuxtJS Vue application: Best practice to use store

Tags: vuex, nuxtjs

I am trying to use nuxtjs for ssr. I am not sure should I use vuex for all api calls. I could use asyncData hook to call api and use it in page directly without using vuex. I read online tutorials which advice to use store in for almost all api call and use store in page/component. I really don't see the benefit of using vuex for api call and use store for page/component.

Can anyone point me to right direction and point me to the correct article, link or code base?

Answer (score 0):

You're free to design your state the way you want!

Vuex store isn't mandatory at all. Once you really understand how it works, you can decide whether it's worth it or not for your case. It's a matter of personal judgment.

I advise you to forget about using Vuex if you feel like it will be simpler to store your data in your page / components.

Vuex store is mainly designed to share data across different pages / component to avoid having a long chain of props / events. If you don't need that in your case, don't go for it, it will add unnecessary complexity.